# how to highlight button when clicking on it in unity / c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having some issues where when I click on a button image it wont highlight that selected button, I tried doing it as shown below. But for some reason the highlighting part it is not working properly. can anyone help me solve this issue. thanks for the help.

here is my code:

```
    public class CarouselView : MonoBehaviour
{

    private RectTransform rectTransform;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject sliderWrapper;
    public Text statusText;


    public Material highlightMaterial;
    Material originalMaterial;
    GameObject lastHighlightedObject;
    bool highlightSet;

     private void Start()
    {
        rectTransform = sliderWrapper.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        currentItem = 0;


        itemWidth = 300f;
        itemCount = sliderWrapper.transform.childCount;

        highlightSet = false;



    }

   public void Select(string name)
    { 

        if (highlightSet.Equals(true))
        {
            statusText.text += name;
             SetHighlight();

        }
        else
        {
            statusText.text = ""; 
            UnsetHighlight();

        }


    }

   public void SetHighlight()
   {
       // only set highlight if there is a highlighted object
       if (lastHighlightedObject != null)
           highlightSet = true;
   }

   public void UnsetHighlight()
   {
       highlightSet = false;
   }



}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `the highlight part is not working properly`? .. until now you only assign a `bool` value but do nothing else ... In general: Please please don't use `if(highlightSet.Equals(true))` .. where did you take that one from? It is rather simply `if(highlightSet)` or `if(!highlightSet)`. Also using `!=null` for the Unity type `Object` is quite expensive. Rather use `if(lastHighlightedObject)` which uses the built-in `bool operator` "Does the reference exist".

Answer (score 1):

You can change the pressed_colour[image: colour].

Comment: Sorry that I sneak in here, but does Unity allow providing a global variable in such cases? Would be useful to change the color of all buttons for example.

Comment: In that case, @AlexGeorg you may want to create a prefab of a button.

Comment: @DaduKhan Thanks for the answer. However, when I choose a color and then run my application and press on the button, the button does not turn to that color.

Comment: Do you have a screen shot?

Comment: @DaduKhan check screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/wdQc2Q4

Comment: @johnmicheals try using the button without the script?